# Is there any easier algorithm in finding the eigenvalues of hollow matrix?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, recursion, diagonalization

I was using the sage's eigenvalues(), but the function takes so much time (exponential growth) for a higher n*n dimension. I would appreciate it if anyone knows is there any shortcut for hollow matrices, so I can make an efficient algorithm. Thanks in Advance!

Generic Structure of a Hollow Matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}0&\ast &&\ast &\ast \\\ast &0&&\ast &\ast \\&&\ddots \\\ast &\ast &&0&\ast \\\ast &\ast &&\ast &0\end{pmatrix}
Example of a Hollow matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}0&2&6&{\frac {1}{3}}&4\\2&0&56&8&0\\9&4&0&2&93\\1&2&4&0&4\\3&9&83&8&0\end{pmatrix}
The difference between the example to mine is that the size is quite extensive; I intend to come up with an efficient algorithm to find eigenvalues() quickly, reducing time complexity. I would appreciate it if any mathematician could cite any research papers, theorems, or anything that might be helpful to my goal.

Comment: What is a hollow matrix?

Comment: Hollow matrix is a matrix that has its main diagonal elements M[i,i] = M[j,j] = 0  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_matrix)

Comment: One lives and learns.

Comment: Why does your example contain the number $79$ on the diagonal?

Comment: Sorry about that, corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hollowness has nothing to do with anything. Sage has a bad algorithm, but in general, determinant of an integer matrix can be computed in time only slightly worse than for floating point (one way is to use chinese remaindering: compute the determinant mod a bunch of primes, then reconstitute). Yes, I know your matrix is not integer, but clear the denominators first.

Comment: I thought I would have an advantage on the recursive process.